# Why does the US government disallow dynamic languages for secure projects?

Tags: code-security, dynamic-languages, government

I know some people that are currently working on a project for the US military (low security level, non-combat human resources type data).

An initial state of the project code was submitted to the military for review, and they ran the program through some sort of security analyzer tool. It returned a report of known security issues in the code and required changes that needed to be implemented before delivery of the final product.

One of the items that needed to be resolved was removal of part of the project that was written in [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) as it is a dynamic language.

What is the background/reason for not allowing a dynamic language to be used in a secure setting? Is this the government being slow to adopt new technologies? Or do dynamic languages pose an additional security risk compared to static languages (ala [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) or [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29))?

Comment: I think it's a little more than that... Do you have the actual rejection reason?  Which branch of the military was it?

Comment: Only way to know for sure is if your acquaintances ask their employers for the reason. But I can risk a guess: static type checking is another layer that helps the correctness of mission-critical software. It won't get rid of bugs, of course, but it's a step in the right direction: the _computer_ is doing some of the work for you. (Yes, I'm aware this is holy wars territory).

Comment: Maybe I'm just pontificating here, but what would define the speed of adoption as being slow or fast? Does the ability to ship a website written using a language justify it as suitable for adoption? Maybe a functional IDE? Or is the ability to statically analyze for known classes of security vulnerabilities define a language as being adoptable?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Unfortunately I do not have access to the rejection reason, this is what I got from a person on that team

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/42912076785/why-is-ruby-bad-security

Comment: You don't want missile control software writen in PHP + JavaScript.

Comment: There are "dynamic" (in the sense of duck typing) languages that don't allow the sort of monkey-patching you can do in Ruby or JS. I'd guess the monkey-patching is the worrisome aspect, not so much the duck typing per se?

Comment: I hesitate to provide an answer, because this is outside my area of expertise. I will offer the opinion that dynamic languages create an environment where decidability is orders of magnitude more difficult than in static languages. In dynamic languages, the distinction between "code" and "data" becomes somewhat subjective. An object can be data in one context, and the same object can be code in some later context.

Comment: HR data is *not* "low security level". I'd expect a company to keep my employment and personal data as secure as they could.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I guess the OP meant that loss of life is not the worst case scenario here.

Comment: Statically typed languages, especially those with few or no type safety escape hatches, let you *prove things* about the behavior of your code, which provides immense help when designing and implementing security-critical systems, where the dynamic language quality assurance standard "dunno, man, try it and see" is simply not enough. Forgetting tiny ad-hoc details like the inconsistency between `nil.to_s` and `[nil].to_s` in Ruby is one major source of bugs in programs.

Comment: @gbjbaanb The type of data in this system is along the lines of: what food was eaten at each meal, amount/type of exercise, and a public q&a about health.  The term HR data was a little misleading, it's more about general health & habits

Comment: @Patrick We can speculate until the end of time why Ruby wasn't allowed in your project.  At the end of the day Ruby wasn't allowed because per the requirements and specifications of the project it was determined supporting Ruby would cause a problem.  The best way to understand the specific reasons is have those people find out what those reasons are.  We can only speculate as a community, through personal experience, most the speculation while has merits are simply wrong.  The US Military has no problem using dynamic programming languages, its often used, when its called for and approved.

Comment: When dealing with a large organization of any type, there's a reasonably decent chance that the requirements are largely arbitrary and/or political. But I agree with Ramhound, the only ones who can answer this for sure are the people who are putting it in the requirements.

Comment: @gbjbaanb you are right i'd expect HR data for forces to be at least secret if not top secret. however the software might be a lower level if it doesn't hold real data yet

Comment: @AndresF. It won't get rid of _all_ bugs but it sure makes a whole category of bugs impossible. Saying it doesn't get rid of bugs is severely understating it...

Comment: @romkyns But that's not what I said. As a fan of static typing, I'm well aware it gets rid of whole categories of bugs, which is what I argued ("another layer that helps the correctness [...]"). I wouldn't use dynamic typing for mission-critical software.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There are a number of 'neat' things that can be done in dynamic languages that can be tucked away in parts of the code that aren't immediately obvious to another programmer or auditor as to the functionality of a given piece of code.

Consider this sequence in irb (interactive ruby shell):

```
irb(main):001:0> "bar".foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for "bar":String
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> class String
irb(main):003:1> def foo
irb(main):004:2> "foobar!"
irb(main):005:2> end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> "bar".foo
=> "foobar!"
```

What happened there is I tried to call the method `foo` in a String constant.  This failed.  I then opened up the String class and defined the method `foo` o return `"foobar!"`, and then called it.  This worked.

This is known as an open class and gives me nightmares every time I think of writing code in ruby that has any sort of security or integrity.  Sure it lets you do some neat things quite fast... but I could make it so every time someone stored a string, it stored it to a file, or sent it over the network.  And this little bit of redefining the String can be tucked anywhere in the code.

Many other dynamic languages have similar things that can be done.  Perl has [Tie::Scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Scalar.html) that can behind the scenes change how a given scalar works (this is a bit more obvious and requires a specific command that you can see, but a scalar that is passed in from somewhere else could be a problem).  If you have access to the Perl Cookbook, look up Recipe 13.15 - Creating Magic Variables with tie.

Because of these things (and others often part of dynamic languages), many approaches to static analysis of security in code doesn't work.  [Perl and Undecidability](http://www.jeffreykegler.com/Home/perl-and-undecidability) shows this to be the case and points out even such trivial problems with syntax highlighting (`whatever  / 25 ; # / ; die "this dies!";` poses challenges because the `whatever` can be defined to take arguments or not *at runtime* completely defeating a syntax highlighter or static analyzer).

---

This can get even more interesting in Ruby with the ability to access the environment that a closure was defined in (see [YouTube: Keeping Ruby Reasonable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbX5BVCKiNs) from RubyConf 2011 by Joshua Ballanco).  I was made aware of this video from an [Ars Technica comment by MouseTheLuckyDog](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/why-does-the-government-disallow-dynamic-languages/?comments=1&post=26104301).

Consider the following code:

```rb
def mal(&block)
    puts ">:)"
    block.call
    t = block.binding.eval('(self.methods - Object.methods).sample')
    block.binding.eval <<-END
        def #{t.to_s}
          raise 'MWHWAHAW!'
        end
    END
end

class Foo
    def bar
        puts "bar"
    end

    def qux
        mal do
            puts "qux"
        end
    end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar
f.qux

f.bar
f.qux
```

This code is fully visible, but the `mal` method could be somewhere else... and with open classes, of course, it could be redefined somewhere else.

Running this code:

```
~/$ ruby foo.rb 
bar
>:)
qux
bar
b.rb:20:in `qux': MWHWAHAW! (RuntimeError)
    from b.rb:30:in `'
~/$ ruby foo.rb 
bar
>:)
qux
b.rb:20:in `bar': MWHWAHAW! (RuntimeError)
    from b.rb:29:in `'
```

In this code, the closure was able to access *all* of the methods and other bindings defined in the class at that scope.  It picked a random method and redefined it to raise an exception.  (see the [Binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Binding.html) class in Ruby to get an idea of what this object has access to)

> The variables, methods, value of self, and possibly an iterator block that can be accessed in this context are all retained.

A shorter version that shows the redefinition of a variable:

```rb
def mal(&block)
    block.call
    block.binding.eval('a = 43')
end

a = 42
puts a
mal do 
  puts 1
end
puts a
```

Which, when run produces:

```
42
1
43
```

This is more than the open class that I mentioned above that makes static analysis impossible.  What is demonstrated above is that a closure that is passed somewhere else, carries with it the full environment that it was defined in.  This is known as a [first class environment](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/First_class_environments#Ruby) (just as when you can pass around functions, they are first class functions, this is the *environment* and all of the bindings available at that time).  One could redefine *any variable* that was defined in the scope of the closure.

Good or bad, complaining about ruby or not (there are uses where one would *want* to be able to get at the environment of a method (see [Safe](http://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html) in Perl)), the question of "why would ruby be restricted in for a government project" really is answered in that video linked above.

Given that:

1. Ruby allows one to extract the environment from any closure
2. Ruby captures all bindings in the scope of the closure
3. Ruby maintains all bindings as live and mutable
4. Ruby has new bindings shadow old bindings (rather than cloning the environment or prohibiting rebinding)

With the implications of these four design choices, it is impossible to know what any bit of code does.

More about this can be read at [Abstract Heresies blog](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iKcoZhehvHwJ:funcall.blogspot.com/2009/09/first-class-environments.html).  The particular post is about Scheme where such a debate was had. (related on SO: [Why doesn't Scheme support first class environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617325/why-doesnt-scheme-support-first-class-environments))

> Over time, however, I came to realise that there was more difficulty and less power with first-class environments than I had originally thought. At this point I believe that first-class environments are useless at best, and dangerous at worst.

I hope this section shows the danger aspect of first class environments and why it would be asked to remove Ruby from the provided solution.  Its not just that Ruby is a dynamic language (as mentioned else-answer, other dynamic languages have been allowed in other projects), but that there are specific issues that make some dynamic languages even more difficult to reason about.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this. You mention a Perl class that allows for changing the behavior of scalars. However, Perl is widely used, including in secure environments. Simply having these capabilities in the language doesn't mean the language can't be used. In the particular case of Ruby, it's likely the fact that the target environment doesn't support Ruby. Personally, I've never seen Ruby available for use on any systems, and I'm not even sure if it's on any approved software lists.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - My understanding of this answer is that the key is `"many approaches to static analysis of security in code doesn't work"`, so it's rejected because it can't be analyzed (by this group, at least).  Whether I'm interpreting it right, or whether that's even a valid reason to reject it, I don't know.

Comment: Lacking information on approved software lists, I can only guess as to the difficulties with dynamic languages.  I have, however, seen similar issues with financial software and the payment card industry checks failing because the language couldn't have static analysis preformed on it for security issues. I demonstrated two examples in dynamic languages where the nature of the language allows it to subvert static analysis.  I also pointed out *why* this, even theoretically, can never be accurate. It may be that perl is allowed in some places and not others, I can only guess as to the reasons.

Comment: You can redefine standard library functions in many other languages as well (for instance Obj-C, C, C++).

Comment: of course, .NET has extension methods now, so you can do your foo() trick using C#! I wonder if .net is also disallowed as its got enough dynamic features to make IronPython and IronRuby viable, or if its just disallowing pure scripting languages for "other reasons".

Comment: Well, .NET extension methods are NOT the same as the above Ruby. They just create an easier way of typing out a static class. They do not actually add a method to a class.

Comment: @MartinWickman the issue that I'm trying to point out isn't if one can redefine standard library functions, but rather if you can write a program that can detect security problems (buffer overruns, unsafe use of user entered values, nefarious object redefinitions) that takes the target program as input.  With many dynamic languages, this is (provably) impossible. When running through "some sort of security analyzer tool" - with no proper static analysis for dynamic languages, this would fail.  I have endeavored to show why this is the case above.

Comment: I believe the term for this is [monkey patching](http://devblog.avdi.org/2008/02/23/why-monkeypatching-is-destroying-ruby/) - mostly used to workaround around bugs or limitations with libraries.

Comment: @dodgy_coder That it is, though its the combination of monkey patching with ruby's open classes (even of core language classes).  This lets one redefine how `String` or `Hash` works at a global level.  Python doesn't have open classes for core language and perl's tie is on a per variable level (one can't redefine how every `%hash` works).

Comment: well, you can do the similarly bad stuff in C, so I don't think that non-obviousness is a valid argument.

Comment: @miraculixx its possible to do evil things in C (see [the underhanded C Contest](http://underhanded.xcott.com)).  However, you can at least be sure that when you write certain code it works the way it is intended.  The examples here are about how *other* code can modify how your code works.  This is much more than what C offers.  C, is also statically typed and thus a mechanical analysis of this *can* go a long way to identifying issues.  But no, you can't redefine a local variable that wasn't passed into another method just by defining a closure (or similar) in C.

Comment: @MichaelT well, if you allow your e.g. C code to accept say another function as a parameter, and you apply this function to your own variables (which is what the Ruby example does), you don't know what's going to happen either unless you have access to the function's actual code. My point being it is not so much the language that makes a program secure or not, it is the programming practice, design, verification and validation that does. While I appreciate and respect your argument & I know it's a common argument, IMHO dynamic languages should not be dismissed based on security considerations.

Comment: @miraculixx in Ruby, if I pass a block of code that was defined in a method to something else, that something else has access to change all of the local variables in the method, or the field, or the iterator that that block of code happens to be part of, or even the self pointer at that point. It can redefine the methods in the class.  I would strongly recommend watching that video and understanding the implications that Ruby's design choices have made for secure coding. Its much more than "insecure code can be written" its that "you can't know what is going to happen."

Comment: This comment is a lengthy discussion of the halting problem, which applies to all common programming languages dynamic or not. It's entirely possible that security people would reject Ruby because it's a dynamic language but that's because they're not good at security or software development, not because of any intrinsic failure of the language itself.

Comment: This argument about security analysability can very well be a fallacy. Code written in static languages tend to be (much) more complex and thus more prone to bugs. Moreover, the examples given in Ruby aren't something an attacker can take advantage of without exploring a security issue in the interpreter, which is well known and reviewed by countless people, unlike any piece of code written by the government or an individual company.

Comment: @Chris Adams: While the halting problem applies to all languages, some languages make it easier to write code for which you can prove certain properties. This does not mean that you can prove the correctness of **any** program but that, if a program is written in a certain way, you can prove certain properties about it.

Comment: @Giorgio: this is technically true but it's a fallacy to claim that this follows the static / dynamic divide. C is a static-typed language but other features make it less provable than a dynamic language like Python which has safer semantics. Java is theoretically better but common design mistakes often lead to people disabling those measures, which says less about the core language than the culture around it.

Comment: @Chris Adams: On both camps you can find "insecure" languages. For static languages I would rather choose Haskell or SML.

Comment: @Giorgio: that was rather my point — it's a mistake to say that a single language tells you much about security when considered in isolation. Implementation quality, culture and tools are far more important.

Comment: @Chris Adams: You are still left with the question of how the most secure static languages compare to the most secure dynamic languages: As far as security is concerned, it is an advantage to check as many properties of a program statically.

Comment: How to do the same in Scala, a static language. `implicit class StringImprovements(val s: String) {def increment = s.map(c => (c + 1).toChar)}`. Then `"HAL".increment` gives `IBM`. [Source](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example).

Answer (score 50):

Assuming the evaluation was security-only, and not just an acceptance scan (that is, they do not accept Ruby because they don't want to support Ruby) then:

**Security analysis tools typically have a bad time with dynamic behaviors.**

For example:

Run any [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) project written with modern features like [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) and [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) through something like [Veracode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veracode) and see what kind of laundry list of false positives you receive in your report.

Veracode even lists many basic techniques within .NET 4 core libraries as "unsupported frameworks" as unsupported or beta only even though most of them are several years old at this point.

**If you are dealing with an entity that has a strong reliance on such a tool they are almost forced to consider those insecure if they do not have the technical expertise, and the resources, to manually evaluate a project and see if it is properly written and secure.**

In civilian operations where computer systems generally don't control anything dangerous or terribly expensive the mitigation is that you discuss the false positives and they are generally accepted as such in bulk.

In banking operations you still have a chance of a false positive mitigation, but you are going to spend a lot more time discussing the minutiae of each item. This rapidly becomes cost prohibitive and you start using more traditional methods.

In the military, aviation, heavy industry and the like, systems can control things that have terrible failure modes those systems so they may have very strict rules about languages, compilers, etc.

**Organizations also generally write their security policy for the worst case they know of, so even if you are writing something trivial, if you are writing it for an organization that has non-trivial systems, the default is generally going to be to hold it to a higher standard unless someone requests a specific exception.**

Comment: And that's just the false positives.  The really worrying thing is the potential for false negatives.

Comment: Honestly, my experience with these tools has generally been awful.  Probably something along a 1/200 to 1/1000 rate of finding something actually worth discussing.  Also, when I get a false positive that I know is something used in thousands of spots in the codebase or the framework and it has only identified it a handful of times I am not exactly filled with confidence.  The problem is that you are effectively implementing a Negative proof when you build one of these tools unless you start out with a formal language like spec#.

Answer (score 33):

Dynamic languages can be used in defense and military applications. I've personally used and delivered Perl and Python in DoD applications. I've also seen PHP and JavaScript used and deployed. In my experiences, most of the non-compiled code that I've seen has been shell scripts and Perl because the environments required are approved and installed on a variety of possible target systems.

The fact that these languages are dynamic most likely isn't the problem. The interpreters for these languages must be approved for use on the target systems. If the interpreter is not approved for use (or, perhaps, it is, but it is not deployed on the target systems), then the language can't be used. Using a given interpreter (or any application) on a secure system requires any number of security hurdles: analysis of the source, the ability to compile from source for target environments, additional analysis of the binaries, ensuring no conflicts with existing infrastructure, etc.

Answer (score 32):

I spent some time interviewing with the DOD (Department of Defense), for a position writing code for the [F-16's MMU](http://www.raytheon.com/capabilities/products/f16_mmc/). Without violating any non-disclosures: the MMU is the computer unit which controls nearly all the F-16's functions. It is (obviously) critical that no errors, such as run-time bugs, occur during flight. It's equally critical that the system perform real-time computing operations.

For this and other historical reasons, all code for this system is written in or compiled to [ADA, a static object-oriented programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29).

> Because of Ada's safety-critical support features, it is now used not
>   only for military applications, but also in commercial projects where
>   a software bug can have severe consequences, e.g. avionics and air
>   traffic control, commercial rockets (e.g. Ariane 4 and 5), satellites
>   and other space systems, railway transport and banking. For
>   example, the fly-by-wire system software in the Boeing 777 was written
>   in Ada.

I hate to quote too much, but this explains really well why exactly static languages (like ADA) are used for projects like this:

> A large number of compile-time checks are supported to help avoid bugs
>   that would not be detectable until run-time in some other languages or
>   would require explicit checks to be added to the source code. For
>   example, the syntax requires explicitly named closing of blocks to
>   prevent errors due to mismatched end tokens. The adherence to strong
>   typing allows detection of many common software errors (wrong
>   parameters, range violations, invalid references, mismatched types,
>   etc.) either during compile-time, or otherwise during run-time. As
>   concurrency is part of the language specification, the compiler can in
>   some cases detect potential deadlocks. Compilers also commonly check
>   for misspelled identifiers, visibility of packages, redundant
>   declarations, etc. and can provide warnings and useful suggestions on
>   how to fix the error.
>
> Ada also supports run-time checks to protect
>   against access to unallocated memory, buffer overflow errors, range
>   violations, off-by-one errors, array access errors, and other
>   detectable bugs. These checks can be disabled in the interest of
>   runtime efficiency, but can often be compiled efficiently. It also
>   includes facilities to help program verification. For these reasons,
>   Ada is widely used in critical systems, where any anomaly might lead
>   to very serious consequences, e.g., accidental death, injury or severe
>   financial loss. Examples of systems where Ada is used include
>   avionics, railways, banking, military and space technology.
>
> Ada's dynamic memory management is high-level and type-safe. Ada does
>   not have generic (and vague) "pointers"; nor does it implicitly
>   declare any pointer type. Instead, all dynamic memory allocation and
>   deallocation must take place through explicitly declared access types.
>   Each access type has an associated storage pool that handles the
>   low-level details of memory management; the programmer can either use
>   the default storage pool or define new ones (this is particularly
>   relevant for Non-Uniform Memory Access). It is even possible to
>   declare several different access types that all designate the same
>   type but use different storage pools. Also, the language provides for
>   accessibility checks, both at compile time and at run time, that
>   ensures that an access value cannot outlive the type of the object it
>   points to.

Comment: *“Because of Ada's safety-critical support features, it is now [used in] commercial rockets (e.g. Ariane 4 and 5)”*, of course [the first Ariane 5 exploded due to a software bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure), so there’s no silver bullet.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: "Although the report identified a software bug as the direct cause, other investigators see the causes as system design failures and management issues" - I seriously doubt that code written in a different language (e.g. Java or C++) would have gotten the rocket to orbit.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Oh I’m not doubting that Ada is still likely superior to others for this application, just noting that it’s not fool-proof. Another language might have let through countless bugs that just wouldn’t have been possible in Ada.

Answer (score 13):

Both DoD and NASA have a long history with programming fails that cost them billions of dollars. Both institutions have accepted processes that should protect them from repeating the same mistakes.

```
Is this the government being slow to adopting new technologies?
```

This is a misconception - dynamic languages are not a new technology, they are quite old. The problem is that if you ever had a problem caused by a dynamic language (e.g. by weak/dynamic typing) and that problem cost you a lot of money, you could accept a policy that would prevent you to do the same mistake again - e.g. banning the use of dynamic languages in sensitive systems.

Dynamic languages will often "swallow" bugs and will end up with some unexpected behavior. This is very dangerous in sensitive systems. If something wrong is happening, you want to know it as soon as possible.

If security is concerned, it would be necessary to see the actual use case. For example, I don't think that a Ruby on Rails web page would be automatically less secure than a Java webpage.

Comment: IMHO more bugs have been "swallowed" by undetected buffer overflows than anything else, which is precisely something that most dynamic languages will not allow in the first place... just saying

Comment: @miraculixx True, there is a reason why Java/C# and similar languages are being used a lot more than Ruby. They are defensive - they check everything. In C/C++ the defensiveness can be enforced by using a good coding standards. You can also enforce checks for everything. But can you imagine writing a sensitive application in ruby or javascript? The possibility for hidden bugs is great.

Comment: Indeed, I can. We likely agree that software needs to be tested thoroughly, independent of programming language. To avoid regressions, testing is best automated using e.g. unit testing, BDD et al. Presuming a professional approach (sensitive application, right?), achieving a sufficient test coverage is a managed process, not left to chance. With that, I doubt that C/C++, Java have an advantage over the likes of ruby or javascript in terms of hidden bugs. Programmer skills? Likely more technical with C++, doubtful with Java, yet hardly a language issue. More technical != quality of product.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add to the existing answers by describing Drupal's [SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.sektioneins.de/en/advisories/advisory-012014-drupal-pre-auth-sql-injection-vulnerability.html), which is a highly critical vulnerability which enables SQL injection and ultimately arbitrary code execution. It is caused by PHP's dynamic typing and lax runtime typing rules.

The entirety of the patch for this issue is:

```
-      foreach ($data as $i => $value) {
+      foreach (array_values($data) as $i => $value) {
```

This code is part of an SQL abstraction layer designed to prevent SQL injection. It takes an SQL query with named parameters, and an associative array which provides a value for each named parameter. The value is allowed to be an array, for cases like `WHERE x IN (val1, val2, val3)`, where all three values can be passed in as a single array value for a single named parameter.

The vulnerability occurs because the code assumes that `$i` in `$i => $value` must be an integer index of the value. It goes on and concatenates this "index" directly into the SQL query as part of a parameter name, because integers don't need any escaping, right?

Unfortunately for Drupal, PHP does not provide such a guarantee. It's possible to pass in another associative array, whose keys are strings, and this loop will happily concatenate the string key into the query, as-is (remember the code thinks it can only ever be an integer).

While there are ways to have a similar error in a statically typed language, they are unlikely. A good developer would consider what possible things `$i` could be before concatenating it into the query. With a statically typed language, it's very easy to enforce that `$i` must be an integer, and in security sensitive code like this, that would most certainly be done.

Furthermore, the code actually checks whether the value is an array before iterating over the items. And herein lies a second part of the fail that enables this vulnerability: both an associative array and a "normal" array return true for `is_array`. While it's also true that in C#, both dictionaries and arrays are `IEnumerable`, it is difficult to construct code which would conflate dictionary keys with array indices like this even intentionally, let alone accidentally.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, official Department of Defense policy does not generally forbid dynamic languages.

Standards for software developed or procured by the DoD are promulgated by 
the [Defense Information Systems Agency](http://www.disa.mil/) (DISA). Their [Application Security - Application Security & Development](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/app-security/app-security/Pages/app-security.aspx) Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG) does not prohibit any particular language. It doesn't mention Ruby, but it mentions Perl and Python which are similarly dynamic. It mentions them in the context of various topics (following established Coding Standards, avoiding Command Injection Vulnerabilities, etc).

Probably what you are seeing is an overly-strict scanning tool (there are several different ones mentioned in the STIG, each may have its own interpretation of the rules) and/or overly-strict interpretation of its output.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a codebase is secure or not depends on how you write your code, how you test it and how you validate and monitor your development and deployment process. Languages are neither secure nor insecure, it's how you code.

The majority of security incidents due to malicious input (sql injections, buffer overflows), viruses, rootkits and trojans. No language can protect you from that.

So banning classes of languages for being "insecure" is not a valid reason.

I suspect that someone, for whatever reason - informed or not - decided to ban these languages. After a while it became an *organizational truth*. It may have been true at that point in time for some projects, but **control cultures** are not keen on changing decisions (admit they were wrong) and rather prefers simple rules. They thrive on rules and regulations and it *does not* matter if they make sense or not, it is the *perceived safety* that counts.

This happens all the time in control cultures. I see it more or less daily. It makes no sense, but that's how it goes. If you want to read more about this highly relevant topic, I recommend Schneider's book "[The Reengineering Alternative](http://www.amazon.ca/Reengineering-Alternative-William-Schneider/dp/0071359818)". Here is a [culture diagram by Michael Sahoto/Agilitrix](http://agilitrix.com/2011/03/how-to-make-your-culture-work/), based on Schneider's book:
[image]

Comment: -1 There are many valid technical reasons why a language would be chosen over another (real-time, static-typing, run-time checks) for safety critical systems. You imply that the reasons are 100% culture, us vs. them, and arbitrary, which IMO is totally incorrect in this case.

Comment: "Languages are neither secure or insecure" -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14313277/602554. Some languages are definitely "more secure" than others.

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe to your liking. I still believe that how secure a system is that it depends more on the code you write than what language you use, although some languages helps avoid certain problems (while, possibly introduces other).

Comment: @MartinWickman: From your own answer "how you validate" - the static typing IS form of validation (depending on type system it can range from 'the expression probably will return integer' or 'the expression probably will return value of class Node' to 'the expression will return an even integer from range 0 to 10 but not 6' and 'the expression will return a proper red-black tree'. Possibility of other forms of validation also depends on language so by your own answer there are more and less secure languages.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka From a purely theoretical perspective, sure. But in reality the majority of security breaches are *not* related to static/dynamic typing at all. Rather, it's almost always about malicious input (sql injections, buffer overflows), viruses, rootkits and trojans on a compromised system. Buffer overflows are almost exclusively possibly in C/C++ btw.

Comment: @MartinWickman: a) SQL/HTML injections and buffer overflows are solved by some type systems - you have different types for escaped and unescaped input so you know which should be treated in what way. b) not all security issues in 'secure projects' necessarily means compromise. I don't want for the software running airplane to have any bug even if it is not a 'security' issue (i.e. cannot be used to take over the system).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Bugs are introduced by the person writing the code. It's funny that pro-static programmers complain about lacking type system in dynamic languages, when programmers who are actually coding in them  don't. Color it which way you want, but it is cultural issue whether you *feel* more safe in a static or dynamic language.

Comment: +1, after dealing with a few Govt organizations, the phrase "informed or not" explains a lot. Holds true of large organizations (biz or govt) in general.

Comment: -1 for factual accuracy problems.  Buffer overflow exploits are a problem highly specific to the C language; you never hear about them in languages that don't allow you to allocate a string buffer on the stack.  And it's not at all difficult to imagine a hypothetical SQL dialect in which the use of Parameters was not simply allowed but **required**.  SQL injection would be impossible in this language.  So yes, a properly-designed language *can* protect you from several common types of attacks.